# Visual Code breakpoints for node after using babel transpiling via gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, babeljs, visual-studio-code

I have a node application that consists of a simple *JavaScript* file called *app.js* written in es6. This is placed in a subdirectory called *source*. I then use a *gulp* build file to transform this using *babel* into standard es5.

This is output inside a directory called *build* along with the generated source map. The node app runs by starting with the app.js that is in the *build* directory.

So the project structure is like this...

```
/
   build
       app.js
       app.js.map
   source
       app.js
   gulpfile.js
   package.json
```

The code runs and works just fine, but I can only debug it by setting a breakpoint in the es5 code at *build/app.js*. I thought with a generated source map it should be possible to set a breakpoint in the original es6 code at *source/app.js* and have it hit that breakpoint instead? It would be much easier to debug if I could set breakpoints and step through the original es6 code instead of the transpiled es5.

Am I doing something wrong or is it simply not possible?